# Finding the equation of a plane, provided a line and a point?

Tags: calculus, vectors

Question: Given the line 
$$\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \\ \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ -3 \\ 2 \\ \end{pmatrix} + t \begin{pmatrix} -2 \\ 4 \\ 7 \\ \end{pmatrix},$$ find a plane which is intersected by the line at the point A[3, -7, -5].

So far, I've found another point on the plane, B[-1,1,9], by subbing 1=t, and found the direction vector of the vector (u=AB) that ended up being [-4,8,14]. I'm currently stuck with finding the normal vector--I keep getting [0,0,0] as an answer. I noticed that it might be because the direction vector found is a scalar multiple of the one of the line, but this is just an assumption.

Does anyone know where I can go from here?

Comment: It suffices to find any two points that are *not* on the line.  Those two points,  and the given intersection point, determine a plane which is intersected by the line.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is looking for parametric equation of this plane: you have point $A$, so the parametric equation is $[3,-7,-5]+t\overline{v}+s\overline{w}$, where $t,s \in \mathbb{R}$. As $\overline{v}$ and $\overline{w}$ you can choose linear independent vectors which aren't parallel to $[-2, 4, 7]$ (because line should intersect the plane), for example $[1,0,0]$ and $[0,1,0]$.

Comment: just to be clear, when finding the linear independent vectors which aren't parallel to [-2,4,7], it can be anything that's not a scalar multiple to [-2,4,7] correct? Ie. your example, [4,1,3] [9,5,2], etc...

Comment: Yes, you're right.

Comment: alright, now say i wanted to take the equation of the plane [x,y,z]=[3,-7,-5]+t[1,0,0]+s[0,1,0] and put it into Ax+By+Cz+D=0 form as that's how my final answer is expected to be stated?

Comment: In this case it's easy to find normal vector to this plane: it's $[0,0,1]$ (you can check), so the plane equation is $0 \cdot x+0 \cdot y+ 1 \cdot z=D$ Next you should find $D$, but you can check that point $[0,0,-5]$ is on plane, so $D=-5$. Genarally this method is quick when you're looking for plane equation in any form, not $Ax+By+Cz=D$.

Comment: yeah I see what you mean. This is a great shortcut, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

There are many possible planes that work here, so why not take the plane whose normal vector is given by the direction vector of the given line? Hence, we know that the plane has the form:
$$
-2x + 4y + 7z = D
$$
for some constant $D$. Now since this plane must contain the given intersection point, substitution yields:
$$
D = -2(3) + 4(-7) + 7(-5) = -6 - 28 - 35 = -69
$$

Multiplying through by $-1$ to make the equation look prettier, we obtain the plane given by:
$$
2x - 4y - 7z = 69
$$

Comment: but isn't the direction vector orthogonal to the normal vector, thus we can't just use the direction vector as the normal vector?

Comment: Draw a line. Now cut the line with a plane at an angle of, say, $90^\circ$. Draw a vector $\vec v$ that is parallel to the line (this is your direction vector). Draw a vector $\vec n$ that is perpendicular to the plane (this is your normal vector). Notice that $\vec v$ and $\vec n$ should be pointing in the same direction! (They might be backwards, but that's fine.)

Comment: in that case, why would we ever have to find the cross product of 2 vectors in order to find the normal when we the direction vector is always in the same direction as the normal?

Comment: You're talking about a separate problem. The direction vector isn't **always** in the same direction as the normal. Note that the line is not contained in the plane, so we know that the direction vector is not orthogonal to the normal vector. In fact, we could have chosen any normal vector, provided that it wasn't perpendicular to the direction vector.